# ASP.NET MVC3 - Controller in each Tab running

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the the thing. I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 to build an app and [Jquery.ui.Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) to show some actions. Basically i want to show in one tab a Requirement controller, press submit and go to another tab with the DocQuality controller. The problem happens when i'm trying to submit information from the Controller Requirement, both validation code are running, obviously,  is not what i want. Any idea or a better way to implement this?

In my **layout** i have the following:

```
<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#tabs-1">Requirement </a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-2">DocQuality</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1">
          { @Html.RenderAction("Create", "Requirement"); }
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-2">
          { @Html.RenderAction("Create", "DocQuality"); }
     </div>
</div>
@RenderBody()
```

View **DocQuality**:

```
@model MvcAppRequirement.Models.DocQuality
@* ... *@
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @* Some parameters *@
}
```

Controller **DocQuality**:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Create(DocQuality docpaseqal)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.DocsPaseQal.Add(docpaseqal);
        db.SaveChanges();  
    }
    @* ... Some fields ... *@
    return PartialView(docpaseqal);
}
```

View **Requirement**:

```
@model MvcAppRequirement.Models.Requirement
@* ... *@
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @* Some parameters *@
}
```

Controller **Requirement**:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Create(Requirement req)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Requirement.Add(req);
        db.SaveChanges();  
    }
    @* ... Some fields ... *@
    return PartialView(req);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extending to what @me2323  said.

```
 @model MvcAppRequirement.Models.Requirement
@* ... *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("","",new{id = "DocQualityForm"})) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     @* Some parameters *@
}
```

jQuery

```
$("buttom").submit(function(){
$("#DocQualityForm").validate();
});
```

same for the other tab view.

overwrite default validation and write your custom validation for each tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve partial validation of a form by conventional methods with MVC. The solution you need is to disable the default validation handler and manually call .validate() on the form inputs you are interested in as and when you want to validate them.